# VNC server without monitor show blank screen

Tags: server, ssh, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, vnc

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on my remote pc.
I used VNC without problem but today I go away and I disconnected the monitor.
This is a stupid idea because now when connecting to my remote pc view only a blank screen.
I can access to the pc only with a VNC viewer.

Do you have any idea to resolve the problem from VNC viewer?
It would be fine to just have access to the terminal without a GUI.

Thanks.

---

[this is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYg7d.jpg)

Comment: use ssh on your remote pc?!

Comment: unfortunately I don't have a public ip from which to access, is it possible to start an ssh connection through vnc server?

Comment: Hello. Simple answer seems to be put the monitor back.

Comment: obviously not being physically there I can't do it ..

Comment: When you can connect remotely via VNC you should also be able to connect via SSH. If you don't have a public IPv4 address, use a public IPv6 address.

Comment: `CaptureMethod = 1` works with RealVNC